# "SHOW VARIABLES" query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to query the list of effective configuration variables (defaults + configured values) just like a "SHOW VARIABLES" statement in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [_settings](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-settings.html) endpoint provides a simple way to retrieve the customized configuration for a given index.

Mapping defaults can only be printed for specific fields calling

`GET /index/_mapping/type/field/content?include_defaults=true`

where *index*, *type* and *content* have to be replaced with the relevant names.